# iPhone Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a iPhone app that uses Push Notifications. My understanding of how this works is I need the "Device Token" of each iPhone before I can send a notification.

Using the test iPhones I have, I can obtain the Device Token from the xcode interface and store them in a data table which the Push Notification PHP script uses to send the notifications.

How do I send the Push Notifications to iPhones that install the app of which I do not know the Device Token ID.

I think my question is; do I need the Device Tokens before I can sent a notification to a iPhone.

If I do require the Device Token, how do I obtain it from iPhones using my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't receive any Push Notification with the Simulator.

You don't directly send a notification. You said to Apple's servers that there is a notification for this Device Token. Then iPhones themselves will ask automatically to receive push notifications is some are available.

To answer to your question : Yes you do. Without the Device Token you can't register your notification to Apple's server. Then you have to implement this register the device to get the DeviceToken:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
```

Comment: Hi Bobbystouket, Point taken on "Simulator". The code you showed in your reply is in my app delegate. I understand that the Device Token is required but does the app send that to the Apple servers, if so how do I then get my PHP script (when it runs) to send the notification if I do not know the Device Token. If an unknow person downloads the app I would not be aware of the Device Token of thier iPhone. Or am I talking complete rubbish?

Comment: Basically you're managing this directly on your own server. You're asking for the Device Token from your Device (only once). Then you sent it to your API each time you want to send a notification. Your API will manage to register the device (only once here too) and add this notification for this device to the Apple Server. If an unknown person does that, it's up to you to send the device token at each start of your application.

Comment: Bobbystouket, thanks again for your reply. I will sit awhile and try to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you should look up == [Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2)

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {
   // other setup tasks here....
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}

// Delegation methods
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];
    self.registered = YES;
    [self sendProviderDeviceToken:devTokenBytes]; // custom method
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}
```

See the code from apple Local and [Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2), first you have to call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes in your app, and then in two delegates, you can get dev token or not, this token is from APNS, so when you get it, you will send it to your service to store it. And you can't get a device token from simulator.

Your push notification service will have to use the device token to send notification to your app, so you will definitely need it. In additional, you will have to get SSL certificates from apple dev center, that requires an valid paid developer ID of iOS.

For more information, please check [Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2), and it's a great help.
Furthermore, I tried this PHP library to test push notification service, and it's good, you can just find its unit test, and paste the device token there, and run it, you will get message from it.

[sly/notification-pusher](https://packagist.org/packages/sly/notification-pusher)